# How to write rails route for /resource_1/{:id}/action/{:resource_2_id}?

Tags: rest, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I just introduced a join table to add `Plants` to `Gardens` and I'm trying to implement this in my first-ever rails app.  I want to

> Add a Plant to a Garden

This seems like a nice restful path: `/plants/{id}/add_to_garden/{garden_id}`, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to write that route.

This makes sense to me, but it doesn't work:

```
resources :plants do
    member do
      post 'add_to_garden/:garden_id'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is:

```
post 'plants/:id/add_to_garden/:garden_id' => 'plants#add_to_garden', as: :add_to_garden
```